# How to change MakeFile to use locally installed libraries instead of source relative path?

Tags: c++, makefile, raspberry-pi, mqtt, mosquitto

I'm trying to get started with the mosquitto MQTT library (c++, raspberry pi).  I think I have successfully installed all of the packages I need, and was able to build and execute the included "temperature_conversion" sample without errors.  I do receive a bunch of warnings about deprecated functions, but I'm ignoring those as not part of the immediate problem.

Though not a complete newbie, I'm not well experienced with linux development tools and building/linking/MakeFiles.  In trying to create my own stand-alone test based on the sample found here:

https://github.com/eclipse/mosquitto/tree/master/examples/temperature_conversion

Output when running 'make' (on my modified version): [edited to include change based on JDAllen's comment]

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/Documents/c/offgrid $ make
g++ main.o mqtt_manager.o -o offgrid -L/usr/local/lib/libmosquittopp.so.1 /usr/local/lib/libmosquitto.so.1
main.o: In function `main':
/home/pi/Documents/c/offgrid/main.cpp:8: undefined reference to `mosqpp::lib_init()'
/home/pi/Documents/c/offgrid/main.cpp:11: undefined reference to `mosqpp::mosquittopp::loop_forever(int, int)'
.
.
(Similar 'undefined reference' messages omitted for clarity)
.
.
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:11: recipe for target 'offgrid' failed
make: *** [offgrid] Error 1
```

My modified MakeFile: [edited to include change based on JDAllen's comment]

```
CFLAGS=-Wall -ggdb -I/usr/local/include
LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/lib/libmosquittopp.so.1 /usr/local/lib/libmosquitto.so.1

.PHONY: all clean

all : offgrid

offgrid : main.o mqtt_manager.o
    ${CXX} $^ -o $@ ${LDFLAGS}

main.o : main.cpp
    ${CXX} -c $^ -o $@ ${CFLAGS}

mqtt_manager.o : mqtt_manager.cpp
    ${CXX} -c $^ -o $@ ${CFLAGS}

clean : 
    -rm -f *.o offgrid
```

UNMODIFIED sample application's MakeFile:

```
CFLAGS=-Wall -ggdb -I../../lib -I../../lib/cpp
LDFLAGS=-L../../lib ../../lib/cpp/libmosquittopp.so.1 ../../lib/libmosquitto.so.1

.PHONY: all clean

all : mqtt_temperature_conversion

mqtt_temperature_conversion : main.o temperature_conversion.o
        ${CXX} $^ -o $@ ${LDFLAGS}

main.o : main.cpp
        ${CXX} -c $^ -o $@ ${CFLAGS}

temperature_conversion.o : temperature_conversion.cpp
        ${CXX} -c $^ -o $@ ${CFLAGS}

clean :
        -rm -f *.o mqtt_temperature_conversion
```

I have verified that /usr/local/include contains mosquittopp.h, and that /usr/local/lib contains libmosquittopp.so.1

Could someone please enlighten me on what I'm missing here?  I'm pretty sure I could make it work by copying the /lib directory structure from the example, but I would like to use the ?installed? versions in /usr because that seems like the way one should go about such things.

[*EDIT1: I have now verified that copying /lib from the example directory into my own and replacing the first two lines in the Makefile with paths relative to those directories does, indeed, allow my modified code to build without the aforementioned errors.  I still want to be able to use the files in /usr/local/lib though - why doesn't this work?  What further steps can I take to see where things are going wrong?*]

If requested, I can update this with my modified code but unless I've done something stupid, it's a structurally equivalent pared down version of the original example linked above.

Comment: So the Sample app has "../../lib/libmosquitto.so.1" in its LDFLAGS, but that is missing from yours.  Maybe the missing functions are in that library file??  Why did you leave it out?

You also might want to change the title of your post, since you actually ask a different question than what the title says.

Comment: @JDAllen Thanks for noticing this - good eye.  Indeed, I did miss it somewhere in my loop of iteration attempts.  It had been in earlier versions and I forgot to put it back in before posting the code.  ***HOWEVER***, the resulting output is the same with it added back in.  Can you suggest a better title for the post?  It seemed like the question I should be asking, but you don't know what you don't know, right?

Comment: Maybe something like "Getting 'undefined reference' when trying to compile MQTT code"??

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't completely understand what's going on in the back-end, but I was able to figure out what works based another discussion with the same/similar problem here:

https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=254740

In case the above link doesn't work, the following is an excerpt from that discussion:

> If you are building some C code as a client you will need "-lmosquitto" at the end of the gcc command.
> That says "use the library libmosquitto" which will resolve all those missing symbols.
> Note that is a lower case "-l", the upper case "-L" indicates a library search path.
> Use "-lmosquittopp" if you are building C++.
> You will need to have installed the mosquitto client development library packages: libmosquitto-dev for C and/or libmosquittopp-dev for C++.

**After a small amount of trial & error, I ended up with the following Makefile that appears to work just fine:**

```
LDFLAGS=-lmosquittopp

.PHONY: all clean

all : offgrid

offgrid : main.o mqtt_manager.o
        ${CXX} $^ -o $@ ${LDFLAGS}

main.o : main.cpp
        ${CXX} -c $^ -o $@ ${CFLAGS}

mqtt_manager.o : mqtt_manager.cpp
        ${CXX} -c $^ -o $@ ${CFLAGS}

clean :
        -rm -f *.o offgrid
```